# Proving a Matrix Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

I am given a matrix inner product on *square* matrices defined as $\langle A,B\rangle=tr(AB^t)$, where $M^t$ denotes the transpose. I am asked to prove that this is indeed an inner product. We go by 3 definitions for inner product: 
$\langle A+B,C\rangle=\langle A,C\rangle+\langle B,C\rangle$

$\langle A,B\rangle=\overline{\langle B,A\rangle}$

$\langle A,A\rangle\geq0$, in particular, $\langle A,A\rangle=0\iff A=0$

I have proven that the defined inner product fits the first and the last definition, but I am having trouble going through the conjugate symmetry proof. This is what I have so far: 
$\overline{\langle B,A\rangle}=\overline{tr(BA^t)}=tr(\overline{BA^t})=tr((\overline{A})\overline{(B^t)})^t$

Comment: For the conjugate symmetry proof , the inner product should be defined as $\langle A,B\rangle=tr(AB^*)$, where $B^*$ is the *transconjugate* of $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** for any compatible matrices $A,B$, we have
$$
\operatorname{trace}(AB) = \operatorname{trace}(BA)
$$

Comment: This is because the $ii$-th entry of $AB$, denoted by $(AB)_{ii}$ is given by $(AB)_{ii}=A_i\cdot B^i$.

Comment: @ellya you should probably clarify the notation you're using (esp $A_i$ for rows/columns).

Comment: $A_i$ is the $i$-th row of $A$, and $B^i$ is the $i$-th column of $B$, and $\cdot$ is the standard inner product.