# Standard inner product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

What is the correct definition of the **standard** inner product of two given matrices?

Answer (score 7):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) the standard matrix inner product on *square* matrices is defined as $\langle A,B\rangle=tr(AB^t)$. The properties are also proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224230/proving-a-matrix-inner-product).

Comment: The matrix doesn't need to be square. The transpose guarantees that the expression works for any dimensions of the matrix ($A$ and $B$ of course must be of the same dimensions). Also note that this is only for real matrices; for complex matrices you need to use the Hermitian transpose (i.e. transpose + complex conjugation).

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that, with this definition (see answer by @Dietrich Burde), the standard inner product of two rectangular real matrices (with the same dimensions) is :

$$\left<A,B\right>=\sum_{1\le i,j\le n}a_{i,j}b_{i,j}$$

which clearly reminds us the way we calculate a (standard) inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ : adding the products of coordinates of the same index.